# Two different applications made ​​with the extension of PhoneGap for eclipse "Applaud" are replaced

Tags: android, applaud

I export my app from eclipse, the app_name is "ANSPE". I install it normally. Later, i export another app named "Valora tu Vida". When i want to install the second app, i get a message with "overriding another app". ANSPE doesnt exist and "Valora tu Vida" installs normally.

I use the same keystore for both apps, but different key for each app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the package names, maybe you called them the same